# How to add "static" block at the end of screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have one editText field, one scroolView field in which there is linearLayout field, which has a lot of elements which are generated programatically, and then I want to add static linear layout field (advert), which would show up at the end of the screen. The problem is that my scrollView takes all of the space in screen, so linearLayout with its content doesn't show up. Also, I have to make sure that if advert is hidden (programatically), then scrollView takes all of available space on the screen. To illustrate this better, here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    // first field: editText - everythings good here
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />

    // second field: scrollView. It chews up a lot of space (height wise) since linearLayout is huge.
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/lLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView" />
    </ScrollView>

    // third field (advert): linearLayout. I want this to be added at the bottom of the screen.
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/advert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to ScrollView add

```
layoutAbove="@+id/advert"
```

**EDIT**

Circular dependency because in your **advert** you are referencing the scrollview
All you need is advert at the bottom of screen.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etInput" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/advert">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
// third field (advert): linearLayout. I want this to be added at the bottom of the screen.

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/advert"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="New Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When you want to remove the advert, set visibility to `invisible` so the view is not removed and scrollview stays always above the advert

Comment: Doesn't work. Got an error: Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can play with margins programatically

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//when you want to show linearlayout
    params.bottomMargin = the height of linear layout;
//when you don't
  params.bottomMargin = 0;
scrollVIew.setlayoutparams(params);
```

or just use ListView and set the linearlayout as a FooterView of the list

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up some stuff.

When you have a fixed block, you should start by placing that block and position everything else relative to that.

So that is untested but might work:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- I am at the BOTTOM! -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <!-- I am at the TOP! -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />

    <!-- and now lets place the scrollview between textview and edittext -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/lLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When you really need your LinearLayout at the bottom (if you want to add more there) just wrap the TextView with a LinearLayout put the layout_alignParentBottom into the LinearLayout and modify the layout_below id of the ScrollView to fit the one from the LinearLayout